# How do I access datast caption and put it in an if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my function display a different description for each image the user clicks on. Right now my function displays a different title depending on the image clicked on and the titles are listed in the dataset-caption. I was going to make a statement for if the title = X, then the innerHTML description will be Y. I cannot figure out why the if statement in the function is not working.

```
                <div class="main-textbox-about-description">
                    <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-text">St. Paul, Apostle of Christ</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="main-textbox-about">
                    <div class="main-textbox-about-saints">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-peter-2176658_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-1" data-caption="St. Peter">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-stylianos-2191792_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-2" data-caption=" St. Stylianos of Paphlagonia">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-demetrius-2176682_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-3" data-caption="St. Demetrius">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/archon-2086750_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-4" data-caption="Arch Angel Michael">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-andrew-2176673_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-5" data-caption="St. Andrew">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/saint-john-the-baptist-1652345_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-6" data-caption="St. John The Baptist">
                        <img src="images/Saint Slide/st-paul-2176669_1280.jpg" class="main-textbox-about-saints-photos main-textbox-about-saints-photos-7" data-caption="St. Paul, Apostle of Christ">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="main-textbox-about-description-long">
                    <h1 class="main-textbox-about-description-long-text">St John the baptist</h1>
                </div>
```

```
const mainText = document.querySelector("h1.main-textbox-about-description-text");
const secondaryText = document.querySelector("h1.main-textbox-about-description-text-long")
const imgContainer = document.querySelector('.main-textbox-about-saints');

imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {


  mainText.textContent = e.target.dataset.caption;

  if(e.target.dataset.caption="St. Paul, Apostle of Christ") {
    secondaryText.innerHTML = "Saint Paul was an Apostle of Christ";
  }
});
```

Comment: 'if' works the most. Instead of comparing ==, you used the assignment =. The assignment results are implicitly converted to 'true'. So you actually have if (true) {... that's why the JS parser doesn't report an error.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (e.target.dataset.caption == "St. Paul, Apostle of Christ") {
    secondaryText.innerHTML = "Saint Paul was an Apostle of Christ";
}
```

Note the double ==.

Btw your binding a click event to the image container (div), not the images themselves.

Comment: How can I go about assigning it to the images themselves as the double and triple paranthesis do not work either.